# Document AI- Newly created labels aren't taken account by Human in the loop

Tags: issue-tracking, cloud-document-ai

Human In The Loop worked fine until now, I trained a few versions of a custom extractor processor.
But when I added new labels in the schema, all the labels of type RECORD disapeared from the HITL interface even tho they were correctly extracted.

I checked the HITL configuration and noticed that the newly created labels were not displayed in the schema of the set label-level filter.

Has anyone encountered the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

(Adding this as an Answer so that Markdown is supported)

I don't think this behavior should be expected. Can you provide more details about the process that occurred?

My understanding is you:

- Created a Custom Document Extractor
- Enabled Human in the Loop
- Ran some documents through HITL and applied corrections.
- Added a new label to the CDE Schema
- All new labels were not added to the HITL interface

What do you mean by "All labels of type RECORD disappeared after adding new labels"?

Did you train a new processor version after adding the new labels to the schema?

Comment: I did train a new version with the new labels and set it as the default version. When I upload a test document all the labels are displayed including the new ones, but then I go to HITL to apply corrections and every parent labels are gone. The weird thing is that I can still see their bounding box if I hover my mouse on it, they aren't in left panel and I can't edit them

Comment: Ok, this sounds like a product issue. Can you please report a new bug using the tool linked here? https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/getting-support#bugs

Provide a detailed description of the issue, along with reproduction steps, screenshots and specific data (with any PII removed).